# Python: Removing a space before a string

Tags: python

`print ("The number is", (roll),'.')`

The number is 5 .

I want to remove the space between '5' and '.'

I have tried a few different methods to remove the space before the period, but I am either getting errors or the same result.

Comment: Try this: roll + ‘.’

Comment: For everyone else like me who's surprised by this: the default separator for multiple parameters in print function is a space, because of which it was adding spaces between each element. You can override this using print(... , sep="")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a string formatting method or concatenating methods. the follwoing will give you same results

```
print (f"The number is, {roll}.")
print ("The number is, {}.".format(roll))
print ("The number is"+' '+ str(roll) +'.')
print ("The number is %s. "%(a))
```

Comment: `print('The number is {}.'.format(roll))`, if you use an older Python version.

Comment: Thank you much for this.  Why does this work?  What is the function of f before the string I want to print?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. I can recommend **f-strings**.

`print ("The number is", (roll),'.')`

becomes

`print(f"The number is {roll}.")`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to your question one of the solution you can do by using .format function.

`print ("The number is {}.".format(roll))`